# Php where to store nonce

Tags: php, nonce

My client prompts the server to initiate his/her order. This is when I generated my nonce using...

```
   $nonce = random_bytes(10);
   var_dump(bin2hex($nonce));
```

the nonce is then sent back to the client using a secure https connection. My plan is to send the order to the server from the client with the nonce that the client received, but were would I store the nonce on my server side? Is it a good idea in a session? Or would it be best for the server to wait for the reply from the client? If this doesn't disrupt traffic.

Comment: Whats it being used for? Is this an API or a standard form.

Comment: This is an API, so this is the transaction of the clients order containing list of their items etc, and I don't won't a relay attack of the same order being sent over and over again to the server.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96689/how-to-store-and-retrieve-nonce-in-practice   You can store them in memory, database, file (!).

Comment: you never need to store nonces; just find a random number generator with enough amount of bits. [Here the mathematical demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068193/how-to-use-a-generated-nonce-in-nodejs-and-do-validation-without-a-database-call#50088697).